# On focus edit input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, selectize.js

I have a select in my section using selectize js , now I want when input is focused to be able to edit the input after selection of any option.

Live demo: [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/3bjwpyae/1/)

HTML

```
  <label>Single selection
    <select id="box">
    </select>
  </label>
```

Here is my js

```
$(function() {

    $('#box').selectize({
                     plugins: ["remove_button"],
                     valueField: 'title',
                     labelField: 'title',
                     searchField: 'title',
                     options: [
                         {id: 1, title: 'DIY', url: 'https://diy.org'},
                         {id: 2, title: 'Google', url: 'http://google.com'},
                         {id: 3, title: 'Yahoo', url: 'http://yahoo.com'},
                     ],
                     render: {
                         option: function(data, escape) {
                             return '<div class="option">' +
                                     '<span class="title">' + escape(data.title) + '</span>' +
                                     '<span class="url">' + escape(data.url) + '</span>' +
                                 '</div>';
                         },
                         
                     },
    });

   //edit input on focus
   $('#box-selectized'). focus(function(){
     console.log('focused');
     $('.select-input').removeClass('full has-items');
     $('#box-selectized').css({'width': 'auto', 'opacity': 1})
     $('#box-selectized').attr('placeholder', 'How are you?');
     $('.selectize-input').addClass('not-full dropdown-active input-active');
     $('.item').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'})
   })
```

});

Problem:

[image]

When the input is focused I am not able to type anything in my input, what is wrong here?

Comment: when u select the option  try to edit after selection

Comment: u dont need to clear the selected option u need to be able to edit without clearing the selected values, if you clear using clear() method it clear everything, I just want to be able to edit. clearing should happend only if you click delete button (x);

Comment: seems like the desired behaviour is limited by selectize authors. even on [the official demo page](https://selectize.dev/demos/2015/01/01/single-item-select/) selected option in not editable. I looked through the [documentation](https://selectize.dev/docs.html) and found no suitable parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this is a `select` type input which doesn't expect the user to be able to type in text. I would suggest using a `text` type input with a `<datalist>`. Ex:

```
<label>Single selection:
<input list="yourlist" type="text"/></label>
<datalist id="yourlist">
  <option value="DIY">
  <option value="Google">
  <option value="Yahoo">
</datalist>
```

Comment: but the search does not work with this solution. did u try it out?

Comment: u can search and select the option u want after that try to edit the selected option assuming u want something else

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do with this code ?

```
    $('#box-selectized'). focus(function(){
     console.log('focused');
     $('.select-input').removeClass('full has-items');
     $('#box-selectized').css({'width': 'auto', 'opacity': 1})
     $('#box-selectized').attr('placeholder', 'How are you?');
     $('.selectize-input').addClass('not-full dropdown-active input-active');
     $('.item').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'})
   })
```

you remove class and hide item, but item still selected it's just hidden, so please explain what's your objective ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).